# Why cant sublime find pygame when i try to import it with my code?

Tags: python, import, pygame, python-3.7

Im working from the crash course python book and trying to use pygame for one of the projects and both python pygame and pip are all updated to the latest versions but when i try to run the code i get the error "ImportError: No module named pygame"

```
import sys 

import pygame 

def run_game():
    #initialize game and create a screen object 
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")


    # Start the mai loop for the game. 
    while True:

        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()


        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Comment: have you installed pygame library

Comment: Can you add more information? Are you sure you are using the correct python interpreter\version?

Comment: I suggest you find where Pygame is installed on your system, then check `print(sys.path)` and figure out why that lib isn't in your path variable (installed as a different user? as root/admin but not for all users?

Comment: pygame is installed fine and works on the regular python idle program and im sure it would work on other text editors as well. it just wont run on sublime. im using 3.7 and im using the newest version of pygame

Answer (score 1):

As per me,this issue is mostly because of **multiple python versions installed in the system** or because of the **specific location of python where pygame is installed, is not found by the editor.**

The same issue I was facing some hour ago, I tried these steps and it worked for me. You can follow if you are using **sublime text as editor**:

***Need to add:***

1. Go to Tools>Build System>(at the bottom)New Build System in the sublime editor.
2. This will open a code file, replace the code with below-given code:
   Code Snippet for Sublime Text 3 (Mac, Linux):

   {
       "cmd": ["path to python", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
       "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }

where the 'path to python' can be found on cmd by:

```
which python
```

copy the path you get and replace the 'path to python'.

3. Then try to build your file.

You can also verify if your proper version of python is taken by the sublime, you can place the below code and try running:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

More information: Setup & Installation: https://youtu.be/RJL6Y761TNE

In this video, there are some changes that need to be done for running this code, if you are using **sublime text as editor**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation working on a project in the Python Crash Course book, 2nd edition on my Mac M1.

First, ensure that pygame is correctly installed in Python3 on your system. Create a simple program to check the Python version number and to prove that pygame is installed, but run it from the command line:

```
    import sys
    print(sys.version_info)
    import pygame
```

If pygame is installed, you should see something like this:

```
    sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
    pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.7)
    Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Note the major, minor and micro version numbers.

Then run the program in Sublime Text. Before it crashes, it should display the Python version info. In my case, they were different because I had done a special installation to support OpenCV, which was an adventure on the Mac M1.

If the versions are different, then check the version used by the command line with:

```
    which python3
```

In my case, the result showed an installation that looked like this:

```
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python3
```

The following modifies the directions from the 2nd edition of the book to use the absolute path for a particular version of Python.

In Sublime Text, go to Tools->Build System->New Build System...

Replace:

```
    {
        "shell_cmd": "make"
    }
```

with the absolute path of Python found with "which python3" (my path is in the example)

```
    {
    "cmd": ["/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"]
    }
```

and Save As Python3-pygame.sublime-build.

That's what worked for me.